# How to convert index of a pandas dataframe into a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, series

How to convert an index of a dataframe into a column?

For example:

```
        gi       ptt_loc
 0  384444683      593  
 1  384444684      594 
 2  384444686      596
```

to

```
    index1    gi       ptt_loc
 0  0     384444683      593  
 1  1     384444684      594 
 2  2     384444686      596
```

Comment: [If after a groupby, you can avoid it entirely with as_index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32059460)

Answer (score 1356, accepted):

either:

```
df['index1'] = df.index
```

or [`.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

---

If you have a multi-index frame with 3 levels of index, like:

```
>>> df
                       val
tick       tag obs        
2016-02-26 C   2    0.0139
2016-02-27 A   2    0.5577
2016-02-28 C   6    0.0303
```

and you want to convert the 1st (`tick`) and 3rd (`obs`) levels in the index into columns, you could do:

```
>>> df.reset_index(level=['tick', 'obs'])
          tick  obs     val
tag                        
C   2016-02-26    2  0.0139
A   2016-02-27    2  0.5577
C   2016-02-28    6  0.0303
```

Comment: You can rename an index into a specific label by passing `names=` in `reset_index`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75753027/19123103) for a demo.

Answer (score 72):

#### [`rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) + [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

You can first rename your index to a desired label, *then* elevate to a series:

```
df = df.rename_axis('index1').reset_index()

print(df)

   index1         gi  ptt_loc
0       0  384444683      593
1       1  384444684      594
2       2  384444686      596
```

This works also for `MultiIndex` dataframes:

```
print(df)
#                        val
# tick       tag obs        
# 2016-02-26 C   2    0.0139
# 2016-02-27 A   2    0.5577
# 2016-02-28 C   6    0.0303

df = df.rename_axis(['index1', 'index2', 'index3']).reset_index()

print(df)

       index1 index2  index3     val
0  2016-02-26      C       2  0.0139
1  2016-02-27      A       2  0.5577
2  2016-02-28      C       6  0.0303
```

Answer (score 55):

To provide a bit more clarity, let's look at a DataFrame with two levels in its index (a MultiIndex).

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['TX', 'FL', 'CA'], 
                                    ['North', 'South']], 
                                   names=['State', 'Direction'])

df = pd.DataFrame(index=index, 
                  data=np.random.randint(0, 10, (6,4)), 
                  columns=list('abcd'))
```

[image]

The `reset_index` method, called with the default parameters, converts all index levels to columns and uses a simple `RangeIndex` as new index.

```
df.reset_index()
```

[image]

Use the `level` parameter to control which index levels are converted into columns. If possible, use the level name, which is more explicit. If there are no level names, you can refer to each level by its integer location, which begin at 0 from the outside. You can use a scalar value here or a list of all the indexes you would like to reset.

```
df.reset_index(level='State') # same as df.reset_index(level=0)
```

[image]

In the rare event that you want to preserve the index and turn the index into a column, you can do the following:

```
# for a single level
df.assign(State=df.index.get_level_values('State'))

# for all levels
df.assign(**df.index.to_frame())
```

Answer (score 43):

For MultiIndex you can extract its subindex using

```
df['si_name'] = R.index.get_level_values('si_name')
```

where `si_name` is the name of the subindex.

Answer (score 15):

If you want to use the `reset_index` method and also preserve your existing index you should use:

```
df.reset_index().set_index('index', drop=False)
```

or to change it in place:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.set_index('index', drop=False, inplace=True)
```

For example:

```
print(df)
          gi  ptt_loc
0  384444683      593
4  384444684      594
9  384444686      596

print(df.reset_index())
   index         gi  ptt_loc
0      0  384444683      593
1      4  384444684      594
2      9  384444686      596

print(df.reset_index().set_index('index', drop=False))
       index         gi  ptt_loc
index
0          0  384444683      593
4          4  384444684      594
9          9  384444686      596
```

And if you want to get rid of the index label you can do:

```
df2 = df.reset_index().set_index('index', drop=False)
df2.index.name = None
print(df2)
   index         gi  ptt_loc
0      0  384444683      593
4      4  384444684      594
9      9  384444686      596
```

Answer (score 13):

This should do the trick *(if not multilevel indexing)* -

```
df.reset_index().rename({'index':'index1'}, axis = 'columns')
```

[image: Code Result]

And of course, you can always set *inplace = True*, if you do not want to assign this to a new variable in the function parameter of rename.

Answer (score 5):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"gi":[232,66,34,43],"ptt":[342,56,662,123]})
p = df1.index.values
df1.insert( 0, column="new",value = p)
df1

    new     gi     ptt
0    0      232    342
1    1      66     56 
2    2      34     662
3    3      43     123
```

Comment: I would suggest adding some discussion about why you think this answer is better than existing answers...

Comment: This approach with the insert method helps to insert a column into DataFrame's left end (first column) location rather than inserting the column at the right end (last column). Therefore, it might be quite useful for some cases. It might be better to explain it through the answer.

Answer (score 4):

To retain the index (that was converted into a column) as index, use a combination of `to_frame()` and `join()`. In particular, this doesn't produce a `SettingWithCopyWarning`, unlike assignment.

```py
df = df.index.to_frame(name='A').join(df)
```

[image: res1]

This works for MultiIndex, too.

```py
df = df.index.to_frame(name=['A', 'B']).join(df)
```

Also, as [Quinten](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73839597/19123103) mentions, since pandas 1.5.0, `rename_axis` + `reset_index` (or `reset_index` + `rename`) syntax have become obsolete. You can directly pass `names=` as an argument to `reset_index()`. Even duplicate column names are allowed if `allow_duplicates=True` is passed (although having duplicate column labels is highly unadvisable).

```py
df = df.reset_index(names=['A', 'B'])
```

[image: res2]

Answer (score 3):

I usually do it this way:

```
df = df.assign(index1=df.index)
```

Comment: That will add the new column to the right of the existing columns, which might be odd. An alternative I found was to use `insert`, like `df.insert(0, 'id', df.index)` where `0` is the column's index.

Answer (score 2):

In the newest version of `pandas` [`1.5.0`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.5.0.html), you could use the function [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.reset_index) with the new argument `names` to specify a list of names you want to give the index columns. Here is a reproducible example with one index column:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"gi":[232,66,34,43],"ptt":[342,56,662,123]})

    gi  ptt
0  232  342
1   66   56
2   34  662
3   43  123

df.reset_index(names=['new'])
```

Output:

```
   new   gi  ptt
0    0  232  342
1    1   66   56
2    2   34  662
3    3   43  123
```

This can also easily be applied with `MultiIndex`. Just create a list of the names you want.