# pandas groupby without turning grouped by column into index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The default behavior of pandas groupby is to turn the group by columns into index and remove them from the list of columns of the dataframe. For instance, say I have a dataFrame with these columns

```
col1|col2|col3|col4
```

if I apply a groupby say with columns `col2` and `col3` this way

```
df.groupby(['col2','col3']).sum()
```

The dataframe `df` no longer has the `['col2','col3']` in the list of columns. They are automatically turned into the indices of the resulting dataframe.

My question is how can I perform groupby on a column and yet keep that column in the dataframe?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56508602/pandas-groupby-returns-extra-index

Answer (score 187, accepted):

```
df.groupby(['col2','col3'], as_index=False).sum()
```

Comment: it is just me or this doesn't work anymore in recent pandas? Tested with version 2.1.0

Answer (score 40):

Another way to do this would be:

```
df.groupby(['col2', 'col3']).sum().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 15):

The following, somewhat detailed answer, is added to help those who are still confused on which variant of the answers to use.

First, the suggested two solutions to this problem are:

- **Solution 1**: `df.groupby(['A', 'B'], as_index=False).sum()`
- **Solution 2**: `df.groupby(['A', 'B']).sum().reset_index()`

Both give the expected result.

---

#### Solution 1:

As explained in the documentation, `as_index` will ask for ***SQL style*** grouped output, which will effectively ask pandas to preserve these grouped by columns in the output as it is prepared.

> **as_index**: bool, default True
>
> For aggregated output, return object with group labels as the index.
> Only relevant for DataFrame input. as_index=False is effectively
> **“SQL-style”** grouped output.

Example:

Given the following Dataframe:

```
     A     B      C      D
0    A     1  0.502130  0.959404
1    A     3  0.335416  0.087215
2    B     2  0.067308  0.084595
3    B     4  0.454158  0.723124
4    B     4  0.323326  0.895858
5    C     2  0.672375  0.356736
6    C     5  0.929655  0.371913
7    D     5  0.212634  0.540736
8    D     5  0.471418  0.268270
9    E     1  0.061270  0.739610
```

Applying the first solution gives:

```
>>> df.groupby(["A", "B"], as_index=False).sum()

     A     B      C        D
0    A     1  0.502130  0.959404
1    A     3  0.335416  0.087215
2    B     2  0.067308  0.084595
3    B     4  0.777483  1.618982
4    C     2  0.672375  0.356736
5    C     5  0.929655  0.371913
6    D     5  0.684052  0.809006
7    E     1  0.061270  0.739610
```

Where the groupby columns are preserved correctly.

---

#### Solution 2:

To understand the second solution, let's look at the output of the previous command with `as_index = True` which is the default behavior of `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` (check [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)):

```
>>> df.groupby(["A", "B"], as_index=True).sum()
               C       D
A    B                    
A    1     0.502130  0.959404
     3     0.335416  0.087215
B    2     0.067308  0.084595
     4     0.777483  1.618982
C    2     0.672375  0.356736
     5     0.929655  0.371913
D    5     0.684052  0.809006
E    1     0.061270  0.739610
```

As you can see, the groupby keys become the index of the dataframe. Using, `pandas.DataFrame.reset_index` (check [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)) we can put back the indices of the dataframe as columns and use a default index. Which also leads us to the same results as in the previous step:

```
>>> df.groupby(['A', 'B']).sum().reset_index()
     A     B      C        D
0    A     1  0.502130  0.959404
1    A     3  0.335416  0.087215
2    B     2  0.067308  0.084595
3    B     4  0.777483  1.618982
4    C     2  0.672375  0.356736
5    C     5  0.929655  0.371913
6    D     5  0.684052  0.809006
7    E     1  0.061270  0.739610
```

---

#### Benchmark

Notice that since the first solution achieves the requirement in 1 step versus 2 steps in the second solution, the former is slightly faster:

```
%timeit df.groupby(["A", "B"], as_index=False).sum()
3.38 ms ± 21.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit df.groupby(["A", "B"]).sum().reset_index()
3.9 ms ± 365 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```