# How do you manipulate contents of csv (Grouping and storing to columns)

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I need some help manipulating the contents of a .csv file.

My file looks like this:

[image: CSV]

I need to group the contents by "Council District" and then by "TYPENAME" and display their totals.
I then need to store the result in 3 different columns like so:

[image: grouped]

I tried accomplishing this with this code:

```py
ds=pd.read_csv(r"myfile.csv")
ds.info()
ds.keys()

ds=pd.read_csv("myfile.csv")
grouped=(ds.groupby(['Council District','TYPENAME']).size().to_frame("Count"))
grouped.to_csv(r"request_by_districtTEST.csv")
print(grouped.head())
grouped.describe(include='all')
grouped.keys()
```

But instead of having 3 separate columns I only get one:
[image]

Anyone knows how can I fix my code so it stores it into 3 separate columns?

Comment: [Stack Overflow Discourages Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).  It is likely the question will be downvoted.  You are discouraging assistance because no one wants to retype your data or code, and screenshots are often illegible.

Comment: Please [provide a reproducible copy of the DataFrame with `to_clipboard`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246/provide-a-reproducible-copy-of-the-dataframe-with-to-clipboard/52413247#52413247)

Comment: `g = df.groupby(['Council District','TYPENAME']).size().to_frame('count').reset_index()` then `g.to_csv('my.csv', index=False)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pandas groupby without turning grouped by column into index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32059397/pandas-groupby-without-turning-grouped-by-column-into-index)

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Thank you very much! that solved my problem!!! Will mark as answer!!!

Answer (score 0):

The Answer is from the comment by [Trenton McKinney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7758804/trenton-mckinney)

```py
g = df.groupby(['Council District','TYPENAME']).size().to_frame('count').reset_index()
g.to_csv('my.csv', index=False)
```