# Pandas group by is not showing the columns based on which group by is done

Tags: python, pandas

I'm running python 3.X on databricks & I'm doing a simple group by operation in pandas using following code

```
d={'Age_class1': 'mean', 'Age_class2': 'mean','Age_class3': 'mean','Age_class4': 'mean','Attendance': 'count'}
df_student14=df_student.groupby(['state','school','Age_class1']).agg(d)
```

Then I'm saving this file in csv using
df_student14.to_csv(filename)
My csv file is showing  following fields

```
state, school,Age_class1,Age_class1,Age_class2,Age_class3,Age_class4,Attendance
```

But df_student14.columns is showing following output

```
Index(['Age_class1', 'Age_class2', 'Age_class3', 'Age_class4', 'Attendance'], dtype='object')
```

Can you let me know how do I get corresponding `'state','school','Age_class1'` in my `df_student14` data?

Comment: add reset_index() at the end

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas groupby without turning grouped by column into index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32059397/pandas-groupby-without-turning-grouped-by-column-into-index)

Comment: @YOBEN_S @MrNobody,it's partly solving my problem. Yes I can see  state & school in my data frame if I'm not considering Age_class1 in group by.But my business logic need Age_class1 in group by & if I'm considering it then I'm getting Error message `cannot insert Age_Class1, already exists` I'm thinking to concatenate Age_Class1 with school in group by & then separate it after group by. Let me know if you have any better approach

Comment: Can you provide some example data?