# pandas - merge and sum nearly duplicate rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame with several rows that are near-duplicates of each other, except for one value. my goal is to merge those rows and sum the distinct value.

here is an example:

```
names   count   subject
A       2       physics
A       3       physics
A       3       chemistry
B       2       literature
B       3       literature
B       1       economics
C       3       physics
C       2       chemistry
```

And here is what I would like:

```
names   count   subject
A       5       physics
A       3       chemistry
B       5       literature
B       1       economics
C       3       physics
C       2       chemistry
```

i tried using the groupby() and this is what I got:

```
df2 = df.groupby(["names","subject"]).agg({"count":"sum"})
```

```
names subject       count
A     chemistry       3
      physics         5
B     economics       1
      literature      5
C     chemistry       2
      physics         3
```

What would be the best way to tackle this issue? I've looked into the groupby() function but I still don't understand it very well.

Comment: add `as_index=False` in groupby arguments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `sort=False` and `as_index=False` for avoid `MultiIndex` in aggregation of `sum`:

```
df2 = df.groupby(["names","subject"], sort=False, as_index=False).agg({"count":"sum"})
print (df2)
  names     subject  count
0     A     physics      5
1     A   chemistry      3
2     B  literature      5
3     B   economics      1
4     C     physics      3
5     C   chemistry      2
```

If need change order pass list of columns names:

```
df2 = df2[['names','count','subject']]
print (df2)
  names  count     subject
0     A      5     physics
1     A      3   chemistry
2     B      5  literature
3     B      1   economics
4     C      3     physics
5     C      2   chemistry
```

Also is possible pass original columns names (if columns passed to `groupby` and after `groupby`):

```
df2 = (df.groupby(["names","subject"], sort=False, as_index=False)["count"]
         .sum()
         .reindex(df.columns, axis=1))
print (df2)
  names  count     subject
0     A      5     physics
1     A      3   chemistry
2     B      5  literature
3     B      1   economics
4     C      3     physics
5     C      2   chemistry
```

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32059397/pandas-groupby-without-turning-grouped-by-column-into-index

Comment: @ShubhamSharma - ya, very close.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma - difference `sort=False` and ordering of columns

Answer (score 1):

Simply specify as_index=False:

```py
df.groupby(["names","subject"], as_index=False).sum()
```