# panda groupby error and cant call for variable

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by

I noticed after I do a groupby in a dataframe and try to read the entire dataframe after that, the variable used for groupby doesnt show.

```
abc_df= merged_df.groupby[['Name', 'Gender']).first
```

When I try to call the variable `abc_df['Name']`, it doesn't show.

Is there a way to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: `merged_df.groupby[['Name', 'Gender'], as_index=False).first()`. You didn't call the function and grouping columns will be converted to an index by default.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas groupby without turning grouped by column into index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32059397/pandas-groupby-without-turning-grouped-by-column-into-index)

Comment: yes it does!! Thanks!