# Problem with a column in my groupby new object

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

so I have a dataframe and I made this operation:

`df1 = df1.groupby(['trip_departure_date']).agg(occ = ('occ', 'mean'))`

The problem is that when I try to plot, it gives me an error and it says that `trip_departure_date` doesn't exist!

I did this:

`df1.plot(x = 'trip_departure_date', y = 'occ', figsize = (8,5), color = 'purple')`

and I get this error:

`KeyError: 'trip_departure_date'`

Please help!

Comment: That information is now the `index` of your DataFrame and `DataFrame.plot` can only reference columns. `df1.groupby(['trip_departure_date'], as_index=False)` should solve it, or just `reset_index()` after the `groupby`

Comment: the problem is that now, `trip_departure_date` is not a column anymore!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is similar to this question: [pandas groupby without turning grouped by column into index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32059397/pandas-groupby-without-turning-grouped-by-column-into-index)

When you group by a column, the column you group by ceases to be a column, and is instead the index of the resulting operation. The index is not a column, it is an index. If you set `as_index=False`, pandas keeps the column over which you are grouping as a column, instead of moving it to the index.

The second problem is the `.agg()` function is also aggregating `occ` over `trip_departure_date`, and moving `trip_departure_date` to an index. You don't need this second function to get the mean of `occ` grouped by `trip_departure_date`.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv("trip_departures.txt")
```

[image]

```
df1_agg = df1.groupby(['trip_departure_date'],as_index=False).mean()
```

Or if you only want to aggregate the `occ` column:

```
df1_agg = df1.groupby(['trip_departure_date'],as_index=False)['occ'].mean()
```

[image]

```
df1_agg.plot(x = 'trip_departure_date', y = 'occ', figsize = (8,5), color = 'purple')
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, you are right.. the problem is that when I use `as_index = False`, now my only columns are the index and the `occ` column. The `trip_departure_date` column now does not exist. I am trying to aggregate it, but since it is a string column there is no aggregate function that helps me with this.

Comment: Oh, I see what the problem is. I've updated my answer to solve.