# Pandas DataFrame creates new row for index using groupby and sum

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, sum, dataframe

After using the groupby and sum operations as follows:

```
companyGrouped = dailyStocks.groupby(['SYMBOL'])
sumByCompany = companyGrouped.sum()
```

I end up with a new row for the group by and sum key, this is undesirable as I later want to merge this with another dataframe using `[SYMBOL]`. AN image of the table, obtained using: `sumByCompany.head()` is shown below.

I've tried a few things to get round this issue, but trying to manually delete this row and set the index as `'SYMBOL'` does not seem elegant! Thanks for any help!!!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDOv3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with `df.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)`

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20461165/how-to-convert-pandas-index-in-a-dataframe-to-a-column%22SO%20Question%22)