# Pandas Bining and Group By

Tags: python, pandas

I have a feeling this is very simple but I am having a major issue with this.

Say I have the following dataframe in pandas.

```
     price  ordersize
0  0.139664   6.051679
1  0.139665   2.358634
2  0.139665   2.618828
3  0.139665  27.240000
4  0.139665   0.040661
5  0.140060   3.000000
6  0.140100   1.463016
7  0.140128   0.020000
8  0.140418  85.000000
9  0.140427   7.000000
```

This is an orderbook for BCHBTC

As you can see starting at index 1 to index 5 we see a number of orders at the same price.

I need to take this input and get it to bin the data so it outputs another dataframe like this.

```
     price  ordersize
0  0.139664   6.051679
1  0.139665   32.258123
2  0.140060   3.000000
3  0.140100   1.463016
4  0.140128   0.020000
5  0.140418  85.000000
6  0.140427   7.000000
```

I have tried using groupby and other things but It is not giving me the correct output, or gives it in a very weird formating that is hard to work with.

If I could get some help with this that would be much appreciated.

Comment: What are the types of `price`, `ordersize` columns? They are `str` and `float`?

Comment: All items are in float for calculations

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and `sum`:

```
df2 = df.groupby("price").sum()
```

This gets you the new `ordersize`, with the `price` as index. If you want the index back as a column, you can use [`reset_index`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20461206/4042267):

```
df2.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: O_o It didn't do anything.

Comment: @xxen0nxx Then maybe your prices are not actually exactly the same, just up to the precision shown?

Comment: Let me try this again one sec.

Comment: Very weird, It is just outputting the same as the last dataframe. The price precision is as shown it's just I am trying to get the cumulative amount of coins at a specific price level.

Answer (score 0):

Use, `groupby` with `as_index=False`:

```
df = df.groupby('price', as_index=False)['ordersize'].sum()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
      price  ordersize
0  0.139664   6.051679
1  0.139665  32.258123
2  0.140060   3.000000
3  0.140100   1.463016
4  0.140128   0.020000
5  0.140418  85.000000
6  0.140427   7.000000
```

Comment: Did not work, just gave me a dataframe with the same as the input.

Comment: @xxen0nxx In this example, you have three input values for price 0.1396665, the output has one value for that price.  from 9 records to 6 records.   Do you need to create price ranges?

Comment: When I print the dataframe though it gives me the exact same as the dataframe I fed into it, it's like the group by is just not working. It is very confusing.

Comment: @xxen0nxx You are not setting it back.  try df = df.groupby..... the print(df).  groupby is not an inplace operation, you need to assign it back to a variable.

Comment: here is the code i have so far `while True:
    top_of_book = bchbtc_asks.head(10)
    print (type(top_of_book))
    #top_of_book = top_of_book.groupby.size()


    price_mean = bchbtc_asks["price"].mean()

    df2 = top_of_book.groupby('price', as_index=False)['ordersize'].sum()
    print (type(df2))
    time.sleep(5) `

Comment: Okay, you are getting types back right now.  Did you want to look at the data?

Comment: Yes i did just print(df2) and it gave me same dataframe as the input dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

I was using the wrong datatype and it was rounding the float numbers to the wrong decimal place. Turns out I may not even need to use group by anymore.