# Python inside MS Sql

Tags: python, sql-server, t-sql

How can i get set index value as a column inside "sp_execute_external_script" with result set output?

here is my code, i have done all calculation

```
EXEC sp_execute_external_script
@language = N'Python',
@script = @pscript,
@input_data_1 = @sqlscript
WITH RESULT SETS(
 (
     Col1 FLOAT,
     Col2 FLOAT, 
     Col3 FLOAT 
    ));
```

Comment: So you need to have the index of the Pandas Dataframe as a column in the output result set? I'm not sure how to do this but as a work-around could you copy the index to a new column at the end of  your Python script and access it that way?

Answer (score 0):

Take a peek at [this relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20461165/how-to-convert-pandas-index-in-a-dataframe-to-a-column). You can make your index a column in the pandas dataframe for output.

Right before your output within your python script `@pscript` you can add: `df.reset_index(inplace=True)`.

Then in your `WITH RESULT SETS` statement you can add the index column first in the list:

```
WITH RESULT SETS(
(
 MyIndex int,
 Col1 FLOAT,
 Col2 FLOAT, 
 Col3 FLOAT 
));
```

Here is a full simplified example since I can't see your exact code:

```
EXEC sp_execute_external_script  @language =N'Python',
@script=N'
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([5,6,7,8,9,10])
df = pd.DataFrame(s)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
OutputDataSet = df
'
WITH RESULT SETS (( MyIndex int, test int ));
```