# Pandas - How to convert the current index column to data and set the index starting from 0

Tags: pandas, indexing

Pretty new to Pandas. How can I achieve this? Thank you very much!

Before Operation

[image: Before]

After Operation

[image: After]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert index of a pandas dataframe into a column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20461165/how-to-convert-index-of-a-pandas-dataframe-into-a-column)

Comment: Yes, thank you very much!