# Convert Series object into Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, series

i used groupby on a dataframe to get desired results. now Groupby result is a Series object and i want to convert into Dataframe. i have used Pd.Dataframe, but only Qty is coming as column output, Other columns from original table are coming as Index or series or tuple.

Original Dataframe

[image]

Desired output in Dataframe:

[image]

So first I used `groupby` to get `sum` of `Qty`:

```py
StockSummary = StockSummary.groupby(['BussDate','Identifier'])['Qty'].sum()
```

then I tried below to get BussDate and Identifier as columns in a dataframe along with Qty. but no success. BussDate and Identifier are still coming as index/series/tuple in the dataframe.

```py
StockSummary = pd.DataFrame(StockSummary)

StockSummary.reset_index()
```

used unstack() but that moves Bussdate values as columns and Identifier as 1 column. not looking for that solution

Comment: call to_frame() on series

Comment: Possibly helpful: [How to convert index of a pandas dataframe into a column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20461165/1630971)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `to_frame` since the result is a Pandas Series, then reset the index

```py
df.groupby(['BussDate',  'Identifier'])['Qty'].sum().to_frame('Qty').reset_index()
   BussDate Identifier  Qty
0      2019        abc   33
1      2020        xyz  112
2      2021        abc  935
```

You can also use `agg` if you want to avoid calling `to_frame`:

```py
df.groupby(['BussDate',  'Identifier']).agg({'Qty':sum}).reset_index()

   BussDate Identifier  Qty
0      2019        abc   33
1      2020        xyz  112
2      2021        abc  935
```