# How to hide the index column of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, yfinance

Help please, I need to delete the 'date' index column, or else 'date' will appear in the first column with the actions

[image]

```py
heat_ds = pd.DataFrame(columns=['PFE','GS','BA','NKE','V','AAPL','TSLA','NVDA','MRK','CVX','UNH'])

heat_ds['PFE'] = pfizer['Close']

heat_ds['GS'] = goldmans['Close']

heat_ds['BA'] = boeingc['Close']

heat_ds['NKE'] = nike['Close']

heat_ds['V'] = visa['Close']

heat_ds['AAPL'] = aaple['Close']

heat_ds['TSLA'] = tesla['Close']

heat_ds['NVDA'] = tesla['Close']

heat_ds['MRK'] = tesla['Close']

heat_ds['CVX'] = chevronc['Close']

heat_ds['UNH'] = unitedh['Close']
```

Comment: Please check if this helps: [How to convert index of a pandas dataframe into a column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54276300/7789963).

Comment: Date is the index to identify/access the row, You could have another index (eg 0, 1, 2 ..) and remove the Date information but you must have an Index of some kind.

Comment: **Please** read [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest) and fix your post title and text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all `date` represents index. To drop it first reset index to remove `date` from index of dataframe and make it a normal column and then drop that column.

```
heat_ds = heat_ds.reset_index()
heat_ds = heat_ds.drop('index', axis=1)
```

or in one line

```
 heat_ds = heat_ds.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the index is probably not the best approach here.

If you are concerned about display, `Styler.hide_index()` or `Styler.hide()` (depending on your version of Pandas) would work. [Usage examples here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.hide.html).

For my older version of Pandas,

```
df.style.hide_index()
```

in Jupyter cell works just fine. Of course, for exporting to csv, you would use `index=False` if needed.

If you wish to still print the index, but hide the extra offset caused by the index name, you can set the latter to `None`:

```
df.index.name = None
```