# new total column not showing in df.info()

Tags: python, pandas, sum

I have added a Total column using

```
df['Total'] = df[list(df.columns)].sum(axis=1)

My dataframe is
     H1             H2              H3              Total
A    1.643910e+10   5.403600e+09    1.090100e+09    2.293280e+10
B    3.876800e+09   1.056970e+10    6.152400e+09    2.059890e+10
C    2.126470e+10   1.077500e+09    2.858000e+08    2.262800e+10
D    3.911600e+09   3.309300e+09    8.170000e+07    7.302600e+09
```

and the column shows correctly but it is not in the `info()` command, so I cannot use it with a plot. Same issue with the column containing A, B, C, D.

```
df.info()
Data columns (total 3 columns):
#   Column               Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------               --------------  -----  
0   H1                   27 non-null     float64
1   H2                   27 non-null     float64
2   H3                   27 non-null     float64
dtypes: float64(3)
```

I might need to use `inplace = True`, but where?

Thanks for the help.

I expect to run `df.info()` and actually see the first and the Total columns. Right now I only see the original 3 columns.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not in the head() command", and how is it related to being able to use it with a plot? Please, provide [mre] and error/unexpected result.

Comment: This does not make much sense. df.head() shows the first few rows and all the columns. Also note that you could use `df['Total'] = df.sum(axis=1)` if you just want the sum of all columns.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my post. I meant df.info().

Comment: You need to show a full code example, including reading the data, creating the new column and running `df.info()`. And test that (minimal) example yourself. Because if there is anything happening in between the pieces of code (and in a notebook, "in between" can be anywhere; order is not guaranteed), you may get odd results.

Comment: The "the column containing A, B, C, D" is called the index, and is normally not reported with `df.info()`.

Comment: Can  I include the index as a column?

Comment: Most practical is to do that from the outset. Again, we'd have to know how you created or obtained the dataframe. But see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20461165/how-to-convert-index-of-a-pandas-dataframe-into-a-column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could happen if you ran

```
df.info()
```

before you ran the code to create the Total column, or edited the `df['Total']` after you ran the `df.info()`

You can try to restart the Kernel and restart and run all the notebook again. ( Assuming you are working on Jupyter notebook)

Second, Make sure that you got the Total Column first, and after that you can run this code to get the index as a column

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

If you reset the index then you tried to run the originl code to create the Total column,it will give you an error

You don't need to use `inplace = True` here as you are defining a new column with its name

```
df['Total'] = df[list(df.columns)].sum(axis=1)
```

So, try to restart your script or notebook and make sure creating the total column is ran before `df.info()`

Also, try `df.describe()` and see if Total column appears in it as it shows only numerical columns

Comment: Thanks! I accepted this as a solution because it led me to fix the issue. I reset the index, then add the total column with .sum(axis=1, numeric_only = True) because of the new char column and not only numbers and all is good. Thanks All!